# Filter Array of Custom Data Class With NSPredicate in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I have a custom class of data named `DataClass` here is there detail.

```
@interface DataClass : NSObject

@property (assign,nonatomic)NSInteger invoiceID;
@property (assign,nonatomic)NSInteger anInvoiceID;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *customerName;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *departmentName;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *typeNumberOfInvoice;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *invoiceDate;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *stockNumber;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *vehicleDetail;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *rONumber;
@property (assign,nonatomic)NSInteger amount;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *color;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *year;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *location;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *carVinNumber;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *dealership;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *technician;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSData *imageData;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *arrayOfLocations;
```

In my `ViewController` class i have a textfield where i am taking inputs and showing display according to the text. I have a `NSMutableArray` named arrayOfData and filteredDataArray. arrayOfData contains objects of the above `DataClass` but when ever i tried to do this using this code i get error

> 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

```
     NSPredicate *aToZPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY invoiceID CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
    filteredDataArray = [arrayOfData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aToZPredicate];
    [_tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: You want to filter it as per customer name

Comment: try NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY invoiceID CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];

Comment: Remove ANY. Also you cannot use contains with a field of type NSInteger

Comment: Yes sir i want to filter as per name

Comment: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY customerName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comparing with Integer, never use contains. Compare with equal sign

```
NSPredicate *aToZPredicate =
        [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"invoiceID == %d", [searchText intValue]];
        filteredDataArray = [arrayOfData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aToZPredicate];
        [_tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSPredicate *aToZPredicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CAST(SELF.invoiceID, 'NSString') contains[cd] %@", searchText];
filteredDataArray = [arrayOfData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aToZPredicate];
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Sir what if i want to search according to a NSString Object as we cannot use == sign with NSString Objects. Please elaborate this

Comment: Thank you so much Imran bhaii

Comment: @SyedeHussaini If you want to apply contains predicate on Integer, than first you have to CAST that integer to string. You can do this in while creating the predicate   `CAST(SELF.invoiceID, 'NSString')`